# Best approach for graph nodes relationship in Neo4J (Cypher)

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher, relationship

I'm trying to achieve the following data structure in my Neo4J graph database:

`(User)-[:isEmployedBy]->(Company)`
Whereas each "employment" can have multiple "transactions"

Im considering the following options and would like to hear which would be the most "future proof":

Simplest:

```
create
  (matt:Person { name: 'Matt' } ),
  (stackoverflow:Company { name: 'Stackoverflow' }),
  (matt)-[:employed_by { from: date("2000-01-01"), until: date("2010-01-01") }]->(stackoverflow),
  return *
```

However, I couldn't add additional relationships to my employment (such as transactions). I assume my second approach to be my only option? Is this correct? (see below)

```
create
  (matt:Person { name: 'Matt' } ),
  (stackoverflow:Company { name: 'Stackoverflow' }),
  (employment:Employment, { from: date("2000-01-01"), until: date("2010-01-01")}),
  (t1:Payment, { amount: 100 }),
  (t2:Payment, { amount: 50 }),
  (employment)-[:received]->(t1)
  (employment)-[:received]->(t2)
  return *
```

I understand I could attach those transactions directly to the person but I need them directly associated with the job employment, as in: If the person loses the job (connection) all transactions need to disappear.

3) I could also do both connections:

```
create
  (matt:Person { name: 'Matt' } ),
  (stackoverflow:Company { name: 'Stackoverflow' }),
  (employment:Employment, { from: date("2000-01-01"), until: date("2010-01-01")}),
  (matt)-[:employed_by { from: date("2000-01-01"), until: date("2010-01-01") }]->(stackoverflow),
  (matt)-[:has_employment]->(employment)<-[:has_employment]-(stackoverflow)
  return *
```

While I might run into inconsistent data (dates here) would this approach give me a query performance benefit, if say I only wanted to see who was employed by whom without more details/transactions? (using: employed_by).

General question:
Do I want to (or need to) setup bi-directional connections?

```
create
  (matt:Person { name: 'Matt' } ),
  (stackoverflow:Company { name: 'Stackoverflow' }),
  (matt)-[:employed_by { from: date("2000-01-01"), until: date("2010-01-01") }]->(stackoverflow),
  (matt)<-[:employs { from: date("2000-01-01"), until: date("2010-01-01") }]-(stackoverflow),
  return *
```

Again, I'd end up with duplicate information - is there a benefit to this at all?

Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #3 is close to what I'd recommend, except that:

1. The `:employed_by` relationship is redundant and should be omitted to avoid wasting storage, way overcomplicating some queries, and carrying the risk of inconsistencies. The `Employment` node contains the same information.
2. I would avoid using the same relationship type on both sides of the `Employment` node, to avoid confusion and to potentially make future queries more efficient.

*Also, in the standard naming convention used by neo4j, relationship names are in all uppercase (e.g., "HAS_EMPLOYMENT"). It actually helps to make reading your Cypher code easier.*

Comment: ah great! thx for those hints! I will also try to avoild redundancies then!